# How to add CrossFade effect in Textview, Android

Tags: android, string, animation, random

Below code gets a number from two arrays planet_array1 and planet_array, it also randomize the string. Now how can take those two string and add crossfade or fadein effects? Also this code does randomize but stops. How can i add duration that it changes the string automatically after few seconds? i dont want to add any button to change the string.

```
package com.example.androidanimation;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FadeInActivity extends Activity {


        String[] mTestArray;
        String[] mTestArray1;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.sample);

            mTestArray =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
            mTestArray1 =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets1_array);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            updateTextView();    
        }

        private void updateTextView() {
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.randomTextView); 
            TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.randomTextView1); 
            Random random = new Random();

            int maxIndex = mTestArray.length;
            int generatedIndex = random.nextInt(maxIndex);
            textView.setText(mTestArray[generatedIndex]);   
            textView1.setText(mTestArray1[generatedIndex]);  
        }
    }
```

sample.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/randomTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/randomTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="163dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

planet_array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

planet1_array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets1_array">
        <item>Merc</item>
        <item>Ven</item>
        <item>Ear</item>
        <item>Mar</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Final working output

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private TextSwitcher mSwitcher, mSwitcher1;
    private int mCounter = 0;
    String textToShow[] = {
            "Main HeadLine", "Your Message", "New In Technology", "New Articles", "Business News", "What IS New"
    };
    String textToShow1[] = {
            "Main HeadLine", "Your Message", "New In Technology", "New Articles", "Business News", "What IS New"
    };
    int messageCount = textToShow.length;
    // to keep current Index of text
    int currentIndex = -1;

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateTextView();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example_layout);

        mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);
        mSwitcher1 = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher01);
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(setup)
        // Set the factory used to create TextViews to switch between.
        mSwitcher.setFactory(mFactory);
        mSwitcher1.setFactory(mFactory);
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out);
        mSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
        mSwitcher1.setInAnimation(in);
        mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);
        mSwitcher1.setOutAnimation(out);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 0, 1000);

    }

    private void updateTextView() {

        int maxIndex = textToShow.length;
        Random random = new Random();
        int generatedIndex = random.nextInt(maxIndex);
        mSwitcher.setText(textToShow[generatedIndex]);
        mSwitcher1.setText(textToShow1[generatedIndex]);
    }

    private ViewFactory mFactory = new ViewFactory() {

        @Override
        public View makeView() {

            // Create a new TextView
            TextView t = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            t.setTextAppearance(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
            return t;
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to animate only the text, I would suggest you to use [TextSwitcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html).

A `TextSwitcher` is useful to animate a label on screen and it's easy to use.
You just have to set the text to the View and the text would be animated with the animations set with `setInAnimation` and `setOutAnimation`

For scheduling the text changes you can use [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) or a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Using a `Timer` you can schedule a `TimerTask` to repeat at a given delay

```
// ...    
// init view, init TextSwitcher in your onCreate
// ...

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 0, 1000);

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override public void run () {
        updateTextView(); // where you call setText(String) for TextSwitcher views
    }
}
```

Here are some more detailed examples:
- [TimerTask](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html)
- [TextSwitcher](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-textswitcher.html)

Comment: how i can use TextSwitcher without click function? i don't want to use any kind of buttons. i want to use delays, and also i will it work with two sets of texts? and will i be able to randomize the output?

Comment: i'm running into one error, can you please take a look what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You were setting the ViewFactory to the TextSwitchers on every update,  the run method needed to be executed on the main thread, etc. Here is your class, modified to show the animations http://pastebin.com/VDGXPYTT

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on CrossFading views found at the Developer Site for Android:

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html

Here is an almost completed to fade in  animation setup for your textView use something like this:

```
// ** ObjectAnimator Class To animate your first TextView
        ObjectAnimater  animationFadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
        animationFadeIn.setDuration(300);
        animationFadeIn.start();
```

And to Fade out use the same but flip the to and from floats

```
// ** ObjectAnimator Class To animate your first TextView
        ObjectAnimater  animationFadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
        animationFadeOut.setDuration(300);
        animationFadeOut.start();
```

If you want this to work as you say, may want to consider a counter, or possibly offsetting the fade in fade out so your views will show and hide as you want.

Counter logic could be as follows:

```
 // This code will have to be called multiple times, once for each Time you want to Fade
 // Add a timer and start it 

 Timer timer1 = new Timer();


 // pass a different id here when initializing a new UpdateView() Object
 timer1.schedule(new UpdateView(0), 0, 5000);


// Inner Class to Use to run the Animations on your Items
public class UpdateView extends TimerTask
{
  int m_item = item;


  // This id is used to tell which view you want to animate FadeIn
  public UpdateView(int item)
  {
      this.m_item = item;
  }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
       randomize();
   }

   public void randomize(int item)
   {
      Random random      = new Random();
      int maxIndex       = mTestArray.length;
      int generatedIndex = random.nextInt(maxIndex);


      // Switch on the TextView item type using an int
      switch(item)
      {
        // Want to Update an Animate TextView 
        case 0: 

            textView.setText(mTestArray[generatedIndex]);
            animateViewFadeIn(textView);
            animateViewFadeOut(textView1);

        break;
        // Want to Update an Animate TextView 1
        case 1: 
            textView1.setText(mTestArray1[generatedIndex]);
            animateViewFadeIn(textView1);
            animateViewFadeOut(textView);
        break;

      }

   }

   // Fade In
   public void animateViewFadeIn(TextView textView)
   {
        // Do animator Stuff here
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "alpha",0f,1f);
        animation.setDuration(300);
        animation.start();

   }

   // Fade Out
   public void animateViewFadeOut(TextView textView)
   {
        // Do animator Stuff here
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "alpha",1f,0f);
        animation.setDuration(300);
        animation.start();

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but to use this code do i need to create a new class called updateview? i'm somewhat confused, sorry new android developer.

Comment: You can use that as a class inside the Activity Class. And that way you don't have to pass the constructor all your arrays and textViews.